# Can I fetch a registration by device token?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

Is it possible to find a device by device token without downloading all registrations? Should I add the device token as a tag and look it up based on that?

I need to delete prior registrations for a device if a new registration is added on the same device with a new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the device token as tags. Android tokens require two tags because their length exceeds the maximum length of a tag.

```
public static string FormatDeviceTokenTag(int index, string token) => $"DEVICE_TOKEN{index}:{token}";    

public static IList<string> GetDeviceTokenTags(string token)
{
    const int MaxTagLength = 120;

    var tag0 = FormatDeviceTokenTag(0, token);

    var tag0Clipped = tag0.Substring(0, Math.Min(tag0.Length, MaxTagLength));

    var tags = new List<string> { tag0Clipped };

    if (tag0.Length > MaxTagLength)
    {
        var tag1 = FormatDeviceTokenTag(1, tag0.Substring(MaxTagLength));

        if (tag1.Length > MaxTagLength)
        {
           throw new ArgumentException("Token too long");
        }

        tags.Add(tag1);
    }

    return tags;
}
```

Then to find matching tokens...

```
async Task<IList<RegistrationDescription>> GetExistingRegistrations(string token, EnumMobileDeviceType deviceType)
{
    var tags = GetDeviceTokenTags(token);

    var registrations = await CreateClient().GetRegistrationsByTagAsync(tags.First(), 10000);

    var registrations2 = registrations.Where(r => tags.Count > 1 ?
        r.Tags.Contains(tags[1]) :
        !r.Tags.Any(t =>
            t.StartsWith(FormatDeviceTokenTag(1, string.Empty), StringComparison.Ordinal)));

    registrations2 = registrations2.Where(r =>
        (deviceType == EnumMobileDeviceType.Apple && r is AppleTemplateRegistrationDescription) ||
            (deviceType == EnumMobileDeviceType.Droid && r is GcmTemplateRegistrationDescription));

    return registrations2.ToList();
}
```

What a lot of fiddly work. Did I miss something in the API?